# Spring WS: What class invokes unmarshalling?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jaxb2

Anyone knows what class actually invokes unmarshalling in spring web-services? I would like to know if it is effective/necessary to call un/marshalling within soap iterceptor. Or is there any more suitable interceptor for working with unmarshalled objects around the endpoint? If yes, I still wish to know how it works internally.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Actually I am using the `org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor` to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint.html) is the Endpoint that unmarshals the request payload into an object and marshals the response object into XML, check out [its invoke() method source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core/2.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint.java#AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint.invoke%28org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext%29):

```
public final void invoke(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    WebServiceMessage request = messageContext.getRequest();
    Object requestObject = unmarshalRequest(request);
    if (onUnmarshalRequest(messageContext, requestObject)) {
        Object responseObject = invokeInternal(requestObject);
        if (responseObject != null) {
            WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
            marshalResponse(responseObject, response);
            onMarshalResponse(messageContext, requestObject, responseObject);
        }
    }
}
```

AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint need a reference to an XML marshaler:

> - Castor XML: org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller
> - JAXB v1: org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb1Marshaller
> - JAXB v2: org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller
> - JiBX: org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller
> - XMLBeans: org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller
> - XStream: org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller

Note that in Spring-OXM, all marshaler classes implement both the Marshaller and the Unmarshaller interfaces to provide one-stop solutions for OXM marshaling, for example [Jaxb2Marshaller](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-oxm/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.java#120), so in applicationContext wire your AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint implementation like this:

```
<bean id="myMarshallingPayloadEndpoint"
    class="com.example.webservice.MyMarshallingPayloadEndpoint">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    ... ...
</bean>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this fulfilled my worries :), was hoping for some interceptor that can be invoked after unmarshalling but before the endpoint method invocation but it seems not to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of [MethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/method/MethodArgumentResolver.html) is responsible for mapping the request payload to an appropriate format (xml Document, Dom4j, Jaxb etc), and this happens right before the endpoint is called. The interceptors only get the raw xml Source(javax.xml.transorm.Source).

If you want to unmarshal the raw xml in an interceptor, then you will have to get a reference to a unmarshaller and do this yourself, there does not appear to be any child of an [EndpointInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/EndpointInterceptor.html) that can provide you an unmarshalled content(considering that it can be unmarshalled to so many different formats).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was wondering if an unmarshalled object can be found in MessageContext or somewhere like that. The suggested solution is exactly what I'm doing but the functionality is getting more complex and now I'm unmarshalling and marshalling on request/response come in the interceptor too so it is done twice. We have generated endpoint so we need to keep it as simple as possible.